# Why am I getting the error that express_jwt__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I'm working on a project with some friends and wanting to start a project with `npm run development` I get this error:

```
const requireSignin = express_jwt__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default()({
                                                                        ^

TypeError: express_jwt__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/controllers/auth.controller.js?:58:73)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/controllers/auth.controller.js?:95:30)
    at Module../server/controllers/auth.controller.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:420:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/routes/user.routes.js?:5:86)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/routes/user.routes.js?:36:30)
    at Module../server/routes/user.routes.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:540:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at Module.eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:17:77)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/express.js?:165:30)
    at Module../server/express.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:468:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./server/server.js?:3:66)
    at Module../server/server.js (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:552:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/mihailomitrovic/Downloads/iteh_projekat/dist/server.generated.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./server/server.js?:1:18)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried looking for solutions and looking at parts of the code but nothing has helped so far, even `import { expressJwt } from 'express-jwt'`. Does it have something to do with importing a module? Can someone please help or at least point me in the right direction?

Since it's referring me to this file, this is the code from `auth.controller.js`:

```
import User from '../models/user.model'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt'
import config from './../../config/config'

const signin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({
      "email": req.body.email
    })
    if (!user)
      return res.status('401').json({
        error: "User not found"
      })

    if (!user.authenticate(req.body.password)) {
      return res.status('401').send({
        error: "Email and password don't match."
      })
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({
      _id: user._id
    }, config.jwtSecret)

    res.cookie("t", token, {
      expire: new Date() + 9999
    })

    return res.json({
      token,
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      }
    })

  } catch (err) {

    return res.status('401').json({
      error: "Could not sign in"
    })

  }
}

const signout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("t")
  return res.status('200').json({
    message: "signed out"
  })
}

const requireSignin = expressJwt({
  secret: config.jwtSecret,
  userProperty: 'auth'
})

const hasAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorized = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id
  if (!(authorized)) {
    return res.status('403').json({
      error: "User is not authorized"
    })
  }
  next()
}

export default {
  signin,
  signout,
  requireSignin,
  hasAuthorization
}
```

Comment: Are you using Babel?